# How to serve retina images?

Tags: 8, media

How to serve images for retina displays? It seams that there is no modules for drupal 8 in stable release. How can we properly set up to serve hi-res for retina displays?

Comment: Core ships with the __Responsive Image__ module, which can be used to serve different versions of an image based on breakpoints. That should allow you serve hi-res images for retina displays.

Answer (score 2):

You also have the chance **to deliver double size low-quality images** always. It is a valid and very popular technique.

You can do it with CSS or use the following module:https://www.drupal.org/project/hires_images

[image: Hi-Res vs No Hi-Res]

Comment: I've already resolve the issue with responsive images module and hires_images are not yet ready for drupal 8. I was lookin for drupal 8 solution.

Comment: The last release for this module in Drupal 8 was in 2013... I doubt it works with the current release.

Comment: @Kevin as you says the 8.x version need an update.

Answer (score -1):

You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/retina_images for drupal 8 as hires_images is still not available.

After installing most core effects will include a `retinify` checkbox that will do the job.

only downside is that it does not work with most effects provided by other modules (i.e. focal point) but there is certainly workarounds